# Bash expand variable in Git Bash on Windows not working?

Tags: windows, git, bash

Why is the following not working (no output):

```
fileRe="-regex '.*\.h'"
find "." -type f $fileRe
```

but the following works (and outputs results)

```
find "." -type f -regex '.*\.h'
```

Working with: `/c/Program Files/Git/bin/bash`

this is not intuitive?

Comment: Shells variable expansions are not like macro expansions (maybe that's what you mean by _this is not intuitive_). You want to use an array here: `fileRe=( -regex '.*\.h' )` and `find . -type f "${fileRe[@]}"`.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more?
on linux the above works allways?

Comment: What should I do when:  `fileRe=( -regex "'$1'")`
I want to quote the expanded arguement $1 ??
This does not work

Comment: You do: `fileRe=( -regex "$1" )` and expand the array as `"${fileRe[@]}"` (with the double quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `find "." -type f -regex '.*\.h'` and press Enter,
the shell interprets the single quotes as the enclosing markers of a fixed string, and uses the enclosed value as the argument to pass to the `find` command.

In contrast with that, when you set `fileRe="-regex '.*\.h'"`,
the value within the double-quotes is stored *as-is* (after variable expansion), and the embedded single-quotes are taken literally.

And then, when you pass `$fileRe` to `find`,
the value is taken as it was stored,
it is not reinterpreted,
so the literal single-quotes in the value remain literal single-quotes.

To achieve what you want, you can use a Bash array instead:

```
fileRe=(-regex '.*\.h')
find . -type f "${fileRe[@]}"
```

The difference in this version from yours is that the arguments passed to `find` are `-regex` and `.*\.h`. The single-quotes are not part of the value, because they were used when creating the value of the array, and they were not embedded in a double-quoted expression.

This behavior is the same in any Bash shell, regardless of the operating system.